# Logo location of a Magento store

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm creatings feeds on several Magento-stores and I would like to add the logo in the feed. But each store uses different themes and therefor  different logo-locations. Is there a command which shows the logo-location independed of the used theme?

Comment: You want to list all the logos used by your stores right???

Comment: Yes, but the logo's are located on different locations. Example somestore.nl/skin/frontend/default/grayscale2014/images/logo.gif and another example somestore.nl/skin/frontend/svk2/default/images/logo.gif